# Convergence of certain rearrangements of conditionally convergent series: proof verification

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I am trying to prove that if I have a conditionally convergent series $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} x_j \to s$ and a rearrangement $\pi: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, such that $\pi(j) \le j + P, \forall j, P\in \mathbb N_0$, then $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} x_{\pi(j)} \to s$.

My attempt:

1. $\{j\}_{j=1}^{n-P} \subset \{\pi(j)\}_{j=1}^{n} \subset \{j\}_{j=1}^{n+P}, \forall n \ge P$.
2. $\forall \frac{\epsilon}{2} > 0, \exists N_1, \forall n \ge N_1, |s_n-s|< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.
3. $x_n \to 0 \implies \forall \frac{\epsilon}{2P} > 0, \exists N_2, \forall n \ge N_2, |x_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{2P}$ and $\sum_{j \in T} |x_j|< \frac{\epsilon}{2},\forall T \subset \{N_2,\cdots \infty \}, |T|=P$
4. $\forall n \ge N_4=\max(N_1,N_2+P), \left|s-\sum_{j=1}^{n} x_{\pi(j)}\right|\\
   =\left|s-\sum_{j=1}^{n-P} x_j-\sum_{\pi(j) \in \{\pi(j)\}_{j=1}^{n} \setminus \{j\}_{j=1}^{n-P}} x_{\pi(j)}\right|\\
   \le \left|s-\sum_{j=1}^{n-P} x_j\right|+\sum_{\pi(j) \in \{\pi(j)\}_{j=1}^{n} \setminus \{j\}_{j=1}^{n-P}} |x_{\pi(j)}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$

$\sum_{\pi(j) \in \{\pi(j)\}_{j=1}^{n} \setminus \{j\}_{j=1}^{n-P}} |x_{\pi(j)}| <  \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ because indexes $\pi(j)$ are from the set $\{n-P+1,\cdots,n+P\}$ and $n-P+1 > N_2$.

Have I proved it?

Comment: Except for a typo (one $=$ should be $\le$), yes. But legibility could be improved by using a bit more natural language

Comment: In spirit of @HagenvonEitzen's comment, the difference between $\sum_{i = 0}^n x_i$ and $\sum_{i = 0}^n x_{\pi(i)}$ is at most
$$
\sum_{j = n-P}^{n+P}|x_j|
$$
and since the original series does converge, albeit conditionally, this sum goes toward $0$ as $n \to \infty$. This leads to a simpler proof.